# How to allow certain IP's accessing an IP:Port range?

Tags: dhcp, vmware, vnc, pfsense

So I have an ESXi server setup with pfSense acting as the DHCP Server for the VM's. I use VNC's to access each VM over the internet (For example with ports :5905,5906,5907 etc.) and I would like to restrict that only certain IP's can access (whitelisted IP's) these VNC Servers and nothing else. In where and how exactly can I do this easily? In pfSense or in the VM's itself, or maybe in ESXi firewall? Would be nice if someone could explain this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Xalyy,

is you try to access your server using VNC from public? if it is you can do port forwarding on your router and then for IP whitelist, you can make a rule on your firewall.

Comment: Yes, the VNC ports are already port forwarded, but how can I do that and what I have to do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: you can setup firewall on every VM or you can using ip access list on the router.